# Add a figure element in pandoc with filters

Tags: pandoc

I'm writing a filter for `pandoc` in python. I'm using `pandocfilters`.

I want to replace a `Para[Image]` with a `Figure[InlineEl1, InlineEl2]`.

`Figure` is not supported by `pandoc`, so I'm using a `RawBlock` to write raw html. The problem is that I don't know the html for `InlineEl1` and `InlineEl2`. I need to let `pandoc` process them.

Possible workaround: use a `Div` and then modify the resulting html file by hand.

Is there a better method?

edit: Or maybe I can put inline elements in a `RawBlock`? I'm just using a simple string for now. I don't know if it's possible as I don't have any documentation available. I'm just proceeding by trial and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of pandoc 2.0, the figure representation in the AST is [still somewhat adhoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3177). It's simply a paragraph that contains nothing but an image, with the image's `title` attribute starting with `fig:`.

```
$ echo '![caption](/url/of/image.png)' | pandoc -t native
[Para [Image ("",[],[]) [Str "caption"] ("/url/of/image.png","fig:")]]

$ echo '![caption](/url/of/image.png)' | pandoc -t html
<figure>
  <img src="/url/of/image.png" alt="caption" />
  <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

See http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-implicit_figures

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. My goal is to produce an html file with proper tags.

Comment: I was sure it didn't but that's because I'm using version 1.x.

Comment: There's a problem, though. I can't add attributes to figure. Is there a way?

Comment: Currently, the HTML writer just puts all attributes on the `<img`, there's an open issue about that: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3928 pull requests welcome!